# Microsoft's SPF determination is different from Google's

Tags: email-server, spam, spf

I have an application sending mails from GoDaddy's smtp server. I set the SPF of the From domain to (the normal human emails use Office 365):

> v=spf1 include:spf.protection.outlook.com include:smtp.secureserver.net  ~all

Gmail recipients receive those application mails marked as trusted. But Office 365 or Outlook recipients get a warning: **This sender failed our fraud detection checks and may not be who they appear to be.**

Which is incorrect?  My SPF record or Microsoft's fraud detection system? Or Google?

---

More:

I have just switched provider from 1and1 to GoDaddy. The same mails were previously received without the fraud warning in Office 365 with the 1and1 SPF record. So it is unlikely that the mail content is suspect.

Comment: What makes you think the SPF record is what triggered the "fraud detection checks"? They most likely have other factors.

Comment: I was under the impression that the SPF is pretty authoritative and trustworthy as only the domain owner has the ability to change it. Isn't that how it is supposed to work?

Comment: That's how it's supposed to work, but in reality it's not. SPF is merely one of many factors in determining if a mail server is trustworthy. IP reputation databases are one of many other factors, and the exact checks MS does are secret, of course.

Comment: Is the `smtp.secureserver.net` include in your original SPF record correct? I get nothing back for `TXT` query on that (but no error which implies some sort of wildcard). Plain `secureserver.net` or `spf.secureserver.net` gives a full SPF record (with lots of DNS lookups included which may be an issue).

Answer (score 3):

Mail nonrepudiation is complicated these days. SPF helps, but is only one component to a pretty wide-ranging trust-framework. In general, the following will help you improve deliverability without fraud warnings, but is not guaranteed.

- An SPF record with `-all`, not `~all`.
- Correctly configured [dkim](/questions/tagged/dkim)
- Having the IP sending your email have a reverse-lookup in the domain sending the mail (not always possible, I know).
- Having agreement between envelope data FROM: and header data From:

The 'problem' with SPF is that it operates on the SMTP envelope data, not the content of the message. This is how you can have something like sendgrid send email 'from' your domain, but the envelope data says sendgrid and the SPF checks go against the sendgrid DNS.

DKIM is a step towards remediating that, as it provides a way to prove that the maintainer of the DNS domain authorized the message to be sent. If you haven't set that up, I strongly recommend you do so.

The final step is to attempt [dmarc](/questions/tagged/dmarc) enforcing. This takes some work, especially for a domain with a lot of third-party mailers in use.